# How to generate iterator with sliding window pairs?

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'd like to create an iterator that for this input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Will contain the following:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

`Peekable` seems ideal for this, but I'm new to Rust, so this naïve version doesn't work:

```
fn main() {
  let i = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    .iter()
    .peekable();
  let j = i.map(|x| (x, i.peek()));
  println!("{:?}", j);
  println!("Hello World!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) method on slices, and then map the arrays into tuples:

```rust
fn main() {
    let i = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        .windows(2)
        .map(|pair| (pair[0], pair[1]));
    println!("{:?}", i.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ed5bd19485bf5ac924e074943fb57e0)

---

If you want a solution that works for all iterators (and not just slices) and are willing to use a 3rd-party library you can use the [`tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) method from itertools.

```rust
use itertools::{Itertools, TupleWindows}; // 0.10.0

fn main() {
    let i: TupleWindows<_, (i32, i32)> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4]
        .into_iter()
        .tuple_windows();
    println!("{:?}", i.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b702d9c9b3129546cde89ead40b12f87)

---

If you're not willing to use a 3rd-party library it's still simple enough that you can implement it yourself! Here's an example generic implementation that works for any `Iterator<Item = T>` where `T: Clone`:

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

struct PairIter<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    iterator: I,
    last_item: Option<T>,
}

impl<I, T> PairIter<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    fn new(iterator: I) -> Self {
        PairIter {
            iterator,
            last_item: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<I, T> Iterator for PairIter<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    type Item = (T, T);
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.last_item.is_none() {
            self.last_item = self.iterator.next();
        }
        if self.last_item.is_none() {
            return None;
        }
        let curr_item = self.iterator.next();
        if curr_item.is_none() {
            return None;
        }
        let temp_item = curr_item.clone();
        let result = (self.last_item.take().unwrap(), curr_item.unwrap());
        self.last_item = temp_item;
        Some(result)
    }
}

fn example<T: Clone>(iterator: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = (T, T)> {
    PairIter::new(iterator)
}

fn main() {
    let mut set = BTreeSet::new();
    set.insert(String::from("a"));
    set.insert(String::from("b"));
    set.insert(String::from("c"));
    set.insert(String::from("d"));
    dbg!(example(set.into_iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a34889a905824ba9b86fa8b6f4017a20)

Comment: FWIW the `itertools` crate provides a [`tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) method which can be used as-is.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`tuple_windows()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) from the `itertools` crate as a drop-in replacement:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    for (a, b) in data.iter().tuple_windows() {
        println!("({}, {})", a, b);
    }
}
```

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```